# Ionic AngularJS complex json data extraction

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic3

I am new to Ionic and I am trying to transfer complex Json data to my html.(Where Ionic comes in handy).

What i mean by 'complex' Json data is, Jsons like this:

```
{
  "Key: "
     [
      {
       "Key: " "Value",
       "Key: " "Value"
      },
      {
       "Key: " "Value",
       "Key: " "Value"
      }
     ]
}
```

The problem here for me is the first key.
I saw some examples for Json formats without this first key, Examples:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imaTBx4jbwY

What I have now is:

My .ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import{HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
  BugList: Object;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient){
    this.http.get('jsonurl').pipe()
    .subscribe(res => this.BugList = res;), 
    (err) => {
      alert("failed loading data");
    });
  }
}
```

and for my html:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let bug of BugList| async">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{bug.Bugs[1].Title}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-title></ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

this gives me the following error:

**ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'**
Which means that i can only use the *ngFor argument for arrays and not complex Json objects, right?

I also saw another example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TD1rKSuC3Zk

he tried it as follows:

```
this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10')
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(res => {
  this.users = res.results;
}, (err) => {
  alert("failed loading json data");
});
}
```

this one leaded me in the direction I am now. I replaced **.map** function with **.pipe** in my .ts file, because .map is outdated. Now i have a error that says **Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'**

Main question is:
I really am struggling with this extra key, without it would not be so hard. is there a way i can do this **dynamic** using the methods shown?

Comment: Can you show us an actual example of the JSON data, and not just a mockup? What does BugList look like?

Comment: Sorry but the data should not be relevant to the question. The layout of the data is. You should understand it if you are familiar with it. It can not be shown because of confidentiality. If it helps, the second video shows exacly the layout of my data.